# Make text bigger in beamer

Tags: beamer, text, size

How can I make my text in the beamer presentation bigger? The size of frametitles and so on are okay, but the normal text in the slide is relatively too small.

```
\documentclass[compress,black]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usefonttheme{serif}
% - I need a darkred background color in the sections bar (at the top) on all slides.
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=red!50!black}

% - Just beneath the sections bar I need a narrow darkblue bar on all slides.
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
    \usebeamerfont*{headline}
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}
    \usebeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
    \usebeamercolor{frametitle}
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
       color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
       color(7ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
     color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2.5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)
     }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg)
    }
}
\makeatother

% - Nothing should be displayed on the bottom bar of the slides (no authorname, no section, etc)
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

% - All text should be in black.
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white}

\title{Long Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{One}
\subsection{One}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{ABC}

    This text is too small!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [beamer user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section "18.2.1 Choosing a Font Size for Normal Text"

> - `\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}`Makes all fonts a little bigger, which makes the text more readable. The downside is that less fits onto each
>     frame.
> - `\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}` Same as the 12pt option.
> - `\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}` Makes all fonts somewhat bigger. Requires extsize to be installed.
> - `\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}` This is about the default size of PowerPoint and OpenOffice.org Impress. Requires extsize to be installed.
> - `\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}` This is really huge. Requires extsize to be installed.

---

**Edit after a MWE was added:**

The above procedure seems to conflict with `\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamerfont*{headline}}`, but you can do

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \usebeamerfont{headline}%
    \colorlet{global.bg}{bg}%
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@barshade}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
       color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2ex)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
       color(7ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
    }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@aboveframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
       color(0ex)=(blue);%
       color(1ex)=(blue);%
       color(2.5ex)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
     }
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@belowframetitle}{\the\paperwidth}{%
      color(0ex)=(global.bg);%
      color(1ex)=(frametitle.bg)%
    }
    \fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: I want to keep the serif font. Is that possible?

Comment: @Nadori See my image, I get the serif font. You get something else?

Comment: I have the same now. I found the mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have the font-size option in `\documentclass[options]{beamer}`.
It works like in traditional LaTeX (8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt) so with `\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}` you have the largest normally available.

I don't know the use of your beamer but it is already pretty big and I don't know if bigger would be better.

Comment: That does not work for my theme and letterstyle. I use \documentclass[ ]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usefonttheme{serif}

Comment: You just have tu put the text size between the brackets : `\documentclass[14pt ]{beamer} \usetheme{Szeged} \usefonttheme{serif}`

Comment: That does not work, I want the size of the text relative to titles and frametitles to be different ...